# SOLR norms for non-text fields

Tags: solr

There is no sense in norms for string and numerable fields, but are norms omitted by default for such fields?

I have old schema without "omitNorms=true" and I'm trying to understand, if omitting norms for non-text fields will reduce memory usage.

**UPD**

I know what are norms about.

I'm asking if norms for non-text fields are omitted by default, or not. Especially, because wiki says, that they are only useful for text fields

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694242/what-is-omitnorms-and-version-field-in-solr-schema

Comment: https://lucidworks.com/blog/scaling-lucene-and-solr/#d0e71

Comment: i'm pretty sure it will cover your question, don't want to double post this answer

Comment: @Mysterion please, read the question once again. I know what are norms about and I've seen that question and article.  I'm asking about if norms for non-text fields are omitted by default, or not. Especially, because wiki says, that they are only useful for text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the documentation here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml

it says:

> omitNorms defaults to true for primitive field types
>               (int, float, boolean, string...)

and later:

> Only full-text fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.

Comment: Oh, nice, thanks, I've somehow seen only second part.