# Solr: How to avoid the score to be diluted by multiple values?

Tags: solr

My collection contain products that have a multivalued `tags` field.

1. One product (P1) may have the tag: "Shoes".
2. Another one (P2) may have the tags: "Shoes", "Sport", "Tennis".

Those products will be boosted by functions taking into account popularity. However, the base score, looking for "Shoes" only, would be: 1.5774288 for P1 and 1.3096721 for P2.

Would it be possible that the score be identical for both products?

It is as if the presence of many tags "dilutes" the relevance, for products having more tags than just "Shoes". This will interfere with the boost functions.

Comment: If you still need the score (so `fq` isn't really an option), setting `omitNorms="true"` on the field should exclude any length of the field from the calculation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694242/what-is-omitnorms-and-version-field-in-solr-schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68089931/solr-how-to-avoid-the-score-to-be-diluted-by-multiple-values#comment120346234_68089931), setting `omitNorms="true"` on the field AND reindexing the collection made it possible to have equal scores.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a [filter query](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/common-query-parameters.html#fq-filter-query-parameter) `fq=Shoes` instead of the query parameter `q=` to filter for the matching documents without affecting the score. A second query parameter to score the results would still be useful, as you can combine both.

> The fq parameter defines a query that can be used to restrict the superset of documents that can be returned, without influencing score.